# HTML/Javascript - setTimeout issues

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="test-1">
    <img id="test" src="thumb1.png" width="15%" onmouseover="over(this)" 
        onmouseout="out(this)">
</div>

<script>
    function over(x) {
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb.webp');
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('width','15%');
        var Delay;
        Delay = setTimeout(thumb2, 4000);
    }

    function out(x) {
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb1.png');
    }

    function thumb2(){
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb2.png');
    }
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Hi, I already did some searches, but nothing satisfactory to fix the problem..

I would like some solution for this:

> The `onmouseover` event is executed, and 1 second later, the
>   `onmouseout` event is also called and `setTime` that was executed by the
>   `over` function continues to count, reproducing a visual bug.

Is there any way to break the `setTimer` called by `onmouseover` event, when the `onmouseout` event is called?

Comment: so you want the timer to interrupt if the mouse is moved out of the element before the countdown is finished?

Comment: @messerbill Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout`

```
<script>
    var Delay;
    function over(x) {
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb.webp');
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('width','15%');
        Delay = setTimeout(thumb2, 4000);
    }

    function out(x) {
        clearTimeout(Delay);
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb1.png');
    }

    function thumb2(){
        document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('src','thumb2.png');
    }
</script>
```

You can see a working example at [w3wchools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_cleartimeout)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You could mark the answer as *correct solution*.